# Formulas not getting evaluated if we are using SxssfTransformer

Tags: jxls

I encountered one problem with Jxls Formulas, they were not getting evaluated to correct result if we are using SxssfTransformer.

final Workbook templateWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(templateFile);

*final PoiTransformer poiTransformer = PoiTransformer.createSxssfTransformer(templateWorkBook, 10000, false);*

However, when I used normal XSSFTransformer, formulas did got evaluated correctly. So my below code worked.

```
final Workbook templateWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(templateFile);
final PoiTransformer poiTransformer = PoiTransformer.createTransformer(templateWorkBook);
```

Does anyone know workaround regarding formulas while using SXSSFTransformer

Answer (score 0):

Try to force formula recalculation in Excel with the following code

```
workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
```